# What might be eating small holes in my bell pepper?

Tags: plant-care, pest-damage, bell-peppers

There appears to be something eating very small holes into my pepper fruits.  At first I suspected an insect, but upon cutting the pepper open there were no signs of investation. One of the holes even didn't even completely break through (though maybe the pepper was healing over an old hole).

I'm thinking it might be birds but it seems odd they would drill a hole then stop. What animal might be doing this and is there anything I can do to mitigate it?

Pics of the damaged areas and insides for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be Earwigs causing this damage. Try placing a damp rolled up newspaper at the base of the plants to trap them and check them often. Drown them in a bucket of soapy water.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but it looks similar to the holes that pill bugs have been chewing in some of my tomatoes for the past couple years. So, maybe it's pill bugs.